# jQuery .hover() problem on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, hover, jquery-hover

I have a little problem with a .hover() in IE8 which works in FF, Chrome and Safari with no problem. IE doesn't give any error or whatsoever. Here is what I have so far:

1. A menu that works with .hover() (This works in IE8)
2. A form that opens from the right with .hover() and the form uses jQuery Form, jQuery Validate and qTip (This works in everything but IE8)
3. Multiple javascript libraries loaded: jQuery 1.5.1, jQuery UI, jQuery Form, jQuery Validate, qTip 2, Colorbox

So here comes the problematic code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //menu works great
  $(".menu").hover(
    function () {
      if(!$(this).hasClass('animated')) {
        $(this).dequeue().stop().animate({top: 137}, 400,'easeInOutCirc');
      }
    },
    function () {
      $(this).addClass('animated').animate({top: 110}, 400,'easeInOutCirc', function() {$(this).removeClass('animated').dequeue();});
    }
  );
  //this works in everything but IE8
  $("#contact-bar").hover(
    function () {
      if(!$(this).hasClass('animated')) {
        $(this).dequeue().stop().animate({right: -10}, 400,'easeInOutCirc', function() {$('.qtip').qtip('show');});
      }
    },
    function () {
      $(this).addClass('animated').animate({right: -301}, 400,'easeInOutCirc', function() {$(this).removeClass('animated').dequeue(); $('.qtip').qtip('hide');});
    }
  );
});
```

The CSS (I tried changing the background or even putting an image):

```
#contact-bar {
  position:absolute;
  top:282px;
  width:352px;
  height:360px;
  right: -301px;
}
```

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Do you have it online? For example on findle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I see there could be problem with html. See screenshot. Why on IE `#Table_02` is in `quisiera-contratar-a-redvel_`?  See validator results: [Error Line 74, Column 37: end tag for "form" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.redvel.cl/servicios.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Tell when you check it.[image]

Comment: never will forget to check with the w3c again